# printf not completely printing the string(no its not because of scanf or not using scanset function)

Tags: c

I am writing a program entab that replaces strings of blanks by the minimum number of tabs and blanks to achieve the same spacing .( I made use of _ to replace blanks so that changes would be visible in the output)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define TABVAL 8
#define MAXLINE 1000 

int Getline_entab(char Line[]) ;
int main(void)
{
    char Line[MAXLINE] ;
    while(Getline_entab(Line) > 1)
        {
        printf("\nAltered Lines :-%s" , Line) ;
        }
    return 0 ;
}

int Getline_entab(char Line[])
{
    char c_input ;
    int index = 0 ;
    int noblanks = 0 ;
    while((c_input = getchar()) != '\n' && c_input != EOF && index < (MAXLINE - 1))
    {
        if(c_input == ' ')
        {
            if((index+1) % TABVAL == 0)
            {   
                Line[index] = '\t' ;
                noblanks = 0;   
            }
            else
            {
                noblanks++ ; 
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            for(; noblanks > 0 ; noblanks--)
            {
                Line[index - noblanks] = '_';
            }
            Line[index] = c_input ;
        }
        index++ ;
    }
        if(c_input == '\n')
        {
          Line[index] = '\n' ;
          Line[++index] = '\0' ;
        }
        else
          Line[++index] = '\0' ;
    return index ;
}
```

OUTPUT -

```
Premier   foot   k
Premier __foot
```

The first line is the input and second line is the output

But on using loop to print , the complete sentence is printed but it does not print it while using printf or puts . Your Help would be appreciated in understanding where i went wrong

Comment: Any reason you don't put a newline character at the end of your `printf`?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to be a logical error. For the input `Pre mier   foot   k`, the output is `Pre_mier___foot __k`.

Comment: It's usually better to avoid using tabs, because their formatting depends on the user's environment.

Comment: @WeatherVane, the code looks like an attempt to make a visualizer of places where tab characters can be used (probably to make file smaller) so I think your comment is out of scope.  It's been overcomplicated a bit, but that's the reason to come here for the PO.  It is a common exercise for beginners (to make a tabber and a detabber program)

Comment: @LuisColorado I see but my text editor is set to have tab size of 4 at the moment. So 8 spaces in the OP's file will only show up 4 spaces here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took some time but finally done.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define TABVAL 8
#define LIMIT 1000 

int Getline_entab(char Line[]) ;
int main(void)
{
    char Line[LIMIT] ;
    while(Getline_entab(Line) > 1)
        {
            printf("\nAltered Lines :-%s" , Line) ;
        }
    return 0 ;
}

int Getline_entab(char Line[])
{
    char c_input ;
    int index = 0 ;
    int noOfBlanks = 0 ;
    while((c_input = getchar()) != '\n' && c_input != EOF && index < (LIMIT - 1))
    {
        if(c_input == ' ')
        {
            noOfBlanks++ ;
            if(noOfBlanks == TABVAL)
            {
                index -= TABVAL - 1;
                Line[index] = '#' ;//Tab insertion
                noOfBlanks = 0;   
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            for(; noOfBlanks > 0 ; noOfBlanks--)
            {
                Line[index - noOfBlanks] = '_';//Blank insertion
            }
            Line[index] = c_input ;
        }
        index++ ;
    }
    if(c_input == '\n')
    {
        Line[index] = '\n' ;
        Line[++index] = '\0' ;
    }
    else
        Line[++index] = '\0' ;
    return index ;
}
```

`Tab`s have been replaced by `#`s and Blanks by `_`s for better readability.
Some of your variable names have also been changed.

### Sample Input

```
Hello Hi          Bye        Bye
Premier        foot    k
```

### Sample Output

```
Altered Lines :-Hello_Hi#__Bye#Bye

Altered Lines :-Premier#foot____k
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out !!! I thought i would never get an answer but you helped out . Thanks once again